# Проблемы с "for" в Python

Tags: python, for

Только начал обучаться Python. Подскажите пожалуйста, "asd" может быть любым? Т.е строкой, целым числом и с плавающей запятой? или что то одно? Так же интересует сам принцип постановки чего-либо на это место в цикле "for", ибо если честно, то я не особо понимаю суть самой программы. (я так понимаю, тут написано, что есть список qw в котором есть значения "z" "x" "c", а дальше задача для asd в списке qw: вывестись на экран. Но мы же не вводили вообще asd. Ни в списке его нет, ни в переменных. откуда оно взялось, и как выполняет команды?

```
qw = ['z', 'x', 'c']
for asd in qw:
    print(asd)
```

Comment: Это переменная цикла. Оператор for на каждой итерации присваивает переменной цикла значение из qw. На первой итерации в asd будет 'z', на второй 'x', на третьей 'c', после чего цикл закончится. Это подробно описано в любом учебнике.

Comment: asd может быть любым. но qw обязан быть итерируемым объектом

Comment: @Интик можно `(:` В Питоне цикл не создаёт отдельный уровень видимости, в итоге переменная доступна после цикла.

Comment: На будущее: попробуйте почитать доки перед заданием вопроса https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Comment: В следующий раз постарайся давать вопросам заголовок, отражающий суть проблемы с которой ты столкнулся, а не просто случайное слово из кода.

Answer (score 5):

### Пошагово

Давайте разберём этот небольшой код подробнее:

1. `qw = ['z', 'x', 'c']` – создаём переменную с именем `qw`, в значение переменной помещается список из трёх элементов (односимвольные строки).
2. `for asd in qw:` – перебираем значения в списке. На каждое значение выделяется так называемая **итерация цикла**, на каждой итерации в значение переменной `asd` ставится один из элементов списка `qw`. Также, для каждой итерации выполняется **тело цикла**, которое идёт после двоеточия на следующих строках с отступом.
3. `print(asd)` – в данном случае тело цикла состоит из одной строки, которая выводит значение переменной `asd`, а эта переменная на каждой итерации цикла хранит одно из значений списка.

Говоря простым языком, программа получается такая:

> Положи в ячейку `qw` список из трёх слов: 'z', 'x', 'c'. Затем последовательно запиши каждое слово из `qw` в ячейку `asd` и выведи её содержимое на экран.

Соответственно, `asd` как имя переменной может быть совершенно любым валидным идентификатором, а значениями этой переменной будут значения из последовательности, по которой происходит цикл.

Сам цикл `for` может выполняться только по последовательностям / итерируемым объектам (iterable), таким как строка (str), список (list), кортеж (tuple), словарь (dict), множество (set).

---

### Посложнее

Для более глубокого понимания процесса можно рассмотреть альтернативную версию этого кода с использованием более общего цикла `while` (который не итерируется по какой-то последовательности, а выполняется пока верно некое условие). Получится сложнее, зато с явным указанием значения переменной `asd`:

```py
it = iter(qw)  # создаём итератор из списка
while True:  # создаём "бесконечный" цикл
    try:  # пробуем взять элемент
        asd = next(it)  # достаём следующее значение из итератора списка
        print(asd)  # выводим его
    except:
        break  # завершаем цикл
```

Нечто вроде этого происходит под капотом цикла `for` – просто там вызов функций `iter`, `next`, а также присвоение переменной происходит скрытно, для лаконичности кода.

---

### Почитать

Если у Вас трудности с пониманием работы циклов в целом, советую хорошенько разобраться в теме, так как это важная алгоритмическая составляющая программирования. Начать можно отсюда:

- [Интерактивный учебник Питона: цикл for](https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/for_loop/)
- [w3schools: Python For Loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

Если интересно глубже погрузиться в тему про итераторы в Питоне, вот неплохие материалы:

- [Хабр: Итерируемый объект, итератор и генератор](https://habr.com/ru/post/337314/)
- [Документация Python 3.8.5: iterable, iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)
- [w3schools: Python Iterators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp)

Answer (score 2):

```
qw = ['z', 'x', 'c']
for asd in qw:
    print(asd)
```

По сути вообще не важно как будет называться переменная цикла хоть asd или любое другое название. Смысл цикла в том что на каждой итерации цикла в твоём случается asd будет изменяться и выводиться

1. z.
2. x.
3. c.

Прочитать можно тут про циклы [Циклы в python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы ранее занимались программированием на си-подобных языках, то для вас должен быть привычен цикл следующего вида:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Но в питоне нет таких циклов в чистом виде. Все циклы в питоне подобны `foreach` из C# или `for (auto&& i : collections)` из C++. То есть эти циклы перебирают все элементы коллекции.

Таким образом, переменная цикла последовательно принимает значения заданной коллекции:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a:
    print(i)

это то же самое, что и

a = [1, 2, 3]

i = a[0]
print(i)

i = a[1]
print(i)

i = a[2]
print(i)
```

Стоит также отметить, что на самом деле перебор коллекции происходит не по индексам, а с помощью методов `__getitem__()`, `__iter__()` и `__next__()`, но об этом вы можете прочитать в документации или в любых учебниках об ООП в питоне.

И да, списки в питоне (также как словари и кортежи) могут содержать одновременно абсолютно любые объекты, как например `int`, `float`, `str`, `list`, `dict`.

Comment: Скорее `for (auto&& i : collection)` тогда

Comment: @dimon а вот и неправда. Если мне мои знания не изменяют, код `for (auto&& i : collection)` перебирает элементы по ссылке, а в питоне `for` перебирает по значению: `a = [[1], [2], [3]]; for i in a: i = [3, 4]; print(a) #[[1], [2], [3]]

Comment: Что значит по значению? Почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/13970074. Попробуйте в вашем примере `i.append(1)` сделать в цикле

Comment: Окей, вы правы. Почему-то присваивание он применяет конкретно к локальной переменной `i`, а не к объекту, который `i` обозначает. Однако хочу заметить, что если присваивание не работает, то нельзя однозначно установить соответствие между циклом из плюсов и циклом из питона.

Comment: В таком случае стоит исправить *Все циклы в питоне эквивалентны <...> `for (auto i : collections)` из C++*, потому что "эквивалентны" и есть "однозначно соответствуют"

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```
qw = ['z', 'x', 'c']
for asd in qw:
    print(asd)
```

***stdout***:

```
z
x
c
```

Это называется итерацией по массиву или списку.
Переменная `asd` по очереди получает все значения из списка `qw`.

---

Цикл `for` используется для перебора последовательности (т. e. cписка, кортежа, словаря, множества или строки).

Оно не очень похоже на ключевое слово `for` в других языках программирования и работает больше как метод итератора, как в других объектно-ориентированных языках программирования.

С помощью цикла `for` мы можем выполнить набор операторов, один раз для каждого элемента в списке, кортеже, множестве
и т.д.

Пример

> Печатает каждый фрукт в списке фруктов:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
```

Цикл `for` не требует предварительной установки индексной переменной.

#### Итерация по строке

Даже строки являются повторяемыми объектами, они содержат последовательность символов:

Пример

> Перебирает буквы в слове "банан":

```
for x in "banana":
    print(x)
```

#### Ключевое слово break

С помощью ключевого слова break мы можем остановить цикл до того, как он пройдет через все элементы:

Пример

> Прекращает цикл при х = "banan"

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
    if x == "banana":
        break
```

Пример

> Выход из цикла, когда x - "банан", но на этот раз перед print'ом :

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
  if x == "banana":
    break
  print(x)
```

#### Ключевое слово continue

С помощью ключевого слова continue мы можем остановить текущую итерацию цикла и продолжить со следующей:

Пример

> Не печатает банан:

```
for x in fruits:
  if x == "banana":
    continue
  print(x)
```

#### range()

Чтоб повторить код с раз используйте  `range()`.

Функция range() возвращает последовательность чисел, начиная с 0 по умолчанию и увеличивая на 1 (по умолчанию) и заканчивая указанным числом.

Пример

> Используя функцию range():

```
for x in range(6):
  print(x)
```

Обратите внимание, что диапазон (6) - это не значения от 0 до 6, а значения от 0 до 5.

Функция range() по умолчанию использует 0 в качестве начального значения, однако можно указать начальное значение, добавив параметр: `range(2, 6)`, что означает значения от 2 до 6 (но не включая 6).

---

Это перевод [этой](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) статьи на русский но не до конца, так что дальше ин инглиш плиз ;)